# Possible to use Objectify in non-blocking mode?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, spotify, nonblocking, objectify

I am building a Spring boot application (Spring 5 and Reactor) and are evaluating Google Datastore as DB.

Since I want my application to be reactive i need a non-blocking Datastore client and I found one developed by Spotify [https://github.com/spotify/async-datastore-client][1] but I would like more help with mapping my Java Bean models to DB.

Google lists Objectify and Catatumbo as third party client libs but from my understanding, they are both blocking.

Is there a way to use these libraries in a non-blocking way? Or are there any other good alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least with Objectify, it's a little more complex than that. Objectify v6 is blocking because the underlying Google library is blocking. However, Objectify v5 is fully asynchronous and v6 inherited this infrastructure - going so far as creating a Future-based facade for the Google library. When Google adds an async API to the SDK, it should be trivial to adapt to Objectify.

All that said, Future-based async APIs are not quite the same as callback or promise-based APIs. Do not expect to see a callback-based API for Objectify anytime soon.